# Pointing DNS name to IP address on local machine

Tags: dns, ip-address, nameservers, static-ip-address

This might be a stupid question but i would really appreciate any compact answer.
I have uploaded a Joomla site on my local machine using a static IP address (213.221.211.111 for example). I have registered a domain (like www.example.com) on Godaddy.com. Within their dashboard, I set the primary and secondary name servers (I looked it from my router setup page). 
Is there any else I need to do so that entering e.g. www.example.com would take the user to 213.221.211.111.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of godaddy, you need to map "www" to your static IP address. It would be a good idea to also map the default entry for your domain, sometimes called "@".

**Edit:** Upon further reading of your original question, you don't set the primary and secondary DNS servers for your domain to your ISP's servers. Your domain's primary and secondary servers are for the addresses of the servers that are responsible for serving **your** domain. Unless you have your domain hosted with your ISP and not with godaddy, then this is not the right thing to do at all. If you have your domain hosted with godaddy, follow their instructions for setting up a domain and pointing "www" at an IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jricher. One thing I am still not clear on DNS servers. As I told you, I have the site up/running on my computer's IP address. I haven't done anything explicit to register it with my ISP. With godaddy, I only registered the domain. Do you think, I should remove the DNS entries of my ISP nameservers from my godaddy dashboard?

Comment: @Ikram: yes, you want to remove your ISP nameservers from your godaddy dashboard unless your ISP is hosting your domain. Basically, it's not enough to just *register* a domain, you need to *host* it as well, and that's the job of the DNS servers. GoDaddy offers domain hosting as well as registration and their panel applications should allow you to point web requests at your server.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what jricher said, you will also probably need to port forward.

Comment: Port forwarding has absolutely nothing to do with setting up DNS, or HTTP forwarding in the webserver if necessary.